# pandas - extract multiple repetitions from df to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DF:

```
geneName   HumanNumber
AHHD        585447
GDFGRE      585447
HFHFR       585447
REWEGD      585447
FDSDD       585447
AHHD        42334
GHRG        42334
REWEGD      42334
FDSDD       42334
...
HFHFR       585447
GDFGRE      585447
AHHD        585447
REWEGD      585447
FDSDD       585447
...
```

`HumanNumber` is a HumanID, `geneName` is a checked gene. In dataframe I have a 80k people. Each people can has 120-200 checked genes.

As U can see one human can be checked 2 or more times. In this example I have `humanID 585447` checked two times in two different institutions. So it need to be analyzed as two different humans, but I can't just change `HumanNumber` - coz it's need to be same as source file to later proccesing.

So I need to create analysis for all samples. Duplicated can't be in same result file. They need be separated.

So my idea:
 - add new column - `indicationCol` for each `HumanNumber` looped by DF. 
 - then df will looks that:

```
geneName   HumanNumber   indicationCol   
AHHD        585447            1
GDFGRE      585447            1
HFHFR       585447            1
REWEGD      585447            1
FDSDD       585447            1
AHHD        42334             2
GHRG        42334             2
REWEGD      42334             2
FDSDD       42334             2
...
HFHFR       585447            3
GDFGRE      585447            3
AHHD        585447            3
REWEGD      585447            3
FDSDD       585447            3
...
```

And now I can pull only HumanNumbers by ID and if df will be no unique it will be possible to pull that second same by `indicationCol` and throw it to another df.

df

```
geneName   HumanNumber   indicationCol   
    AHHD        585447            1
    GDFGRE      585447            1
    HFHFR       585447            1
    REWEGD      585447            1
    FDSDD       585447            1
    AHHD        42334             2
    GHRG        42334             2
    REWEGD      42334             2
    FDSDD       42334             2
    ...
```

df_duplicates:

```
HFHFR       585447            3
GDFGRE      585447            3
AHHD        585447            3
REWEGD      585447            3
FDSDD       585447            3
```

So i wrote a code:

```
name = '585447'
a = 0
df['indicationCol'] = 99999999
df= df.copy()
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df[4].iloc[i] == name:
        df['indicationCol'].iloc[i] = a
    else:
        a = a+1
        name = df[4].iloc[i]
        df['wskaznik'].iloc[i] = a
```

And it's work (despite I got a Copy Warning from pandas) but it's take too long time. After 20 minuts `i == 3263`. Whole df has 15,012,022 rows.

So.. what can I do to upgrade my code. I hope is better way to handle with this problem and I just don't know it.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this chronoligcal way of indicating duplicates we can use `diff` and `cumsum`:

```
df['indicationCol'] = df['HumanNumber'].diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum().add(1)
```

Or `shift` with `cumsum`:

```
df['indicationCol'] = df['HumanNumber'].ne(df['HumanNumber'].shift()).cumsum()
```

**Output**

```
   geneName  HumanNumber  indicationCol
0      AHHD       585447              1
1    GDFGRE       585447              1
2     HFHFR       585447              1
3    REWEGD       585447              1
4     FDSDD       585447              1
5      AHHD        42334              2
6      GHRG        42334              2
7    REWEGD        42334              2
8     FDSDD        42334              2
9     HFHFR       585447              3
10   GDFGRE       585447              3
11     AHHD       585447              3
12   REWEGD       585447              3
13    FDSDD       585447              3
```

---

I would suggest to access each unique group with `GroupBy` on `HumanNumber` and our new column `indicationCol`:

```
for _, grp in df.groupby(['HumanNumber', 'indicationCol'], sort=False):
    print(grp, '\n')

  geneName  HumanNumber  indicationCol
0     AHHD       585447              1
1   GDFGRE       585447              1
2    HFHFR       585447              1
3   REWEGD       585447              1
4    FDSDD       585447              1 

  geneName  HumanNumber  indicationCol
5     AHHD        42334              2
6     GHRG        42334              2
7   REWEGD        42334              2
8    FDSDD        42334              2 

   geneName  HumanNumber  indicationCol
9     HFHFR       585447              3
10   GDFGRE       585447              3
11     AHHD       585447              3
12   REWEGD       585447              3
13    FDSDD       585447              3
```

Answer (score 1):

**Literal Answer to your question**
You can do this process by a counter col:

```
df['indicatorCol'] = (df
                      .duplicated()
                      .to_frame()
                      .groupby([df.HumanNumber, df.geneName])
                      .apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
```

Results:

```
    geneName    HumanNumber indicatorCol
0   AHHD    585447.0    1
1   GDFGRE  585447.0    1
2   HFHFR   585447.0    1
3   REWEGD  585447.0    1
4   FDSDD   585447.0    1
5   AHHD    42334.0 0
6   GHRG    42334.0 0
7   REWEGD  42334.0 0
8   FDSDD   42334.0 0
10  HFHFR   585447.0    2
11  GDFGRE  585447.0    2
12  AHHD    585447.0    2
13  REWEGD  585447.0    2
14  FDSDD   585447.0    2
```

**Faster Way to do it**

You can accomplish the same goal using `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated()`, which essentially is an indicator for duplication.

```
df[df.duplicated(keep='first')] # First to get the first entry and label others as duplications
```

```
    geneName    HumanNumber
10  HFHFR   585447.0
11  GDFGRE  585447.0
12  AHHD    585447.0
13  REWEGD  585447.0
14  FDSDD   585447.0
```

```
unique_df = df[~df.duplicated(keep='first')] # Unique first occurances
duplicated_df = df[df.duplicated(keep='first')] #Duplicates of Unique
```

You can also use `df[~df.duplicated(keep='first')]` the duplicated values of the 1st `DataFrame`.

A bit of explanation on `keep` [argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

> keep : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’
>
> - first : Mark duplicates as True except for the first occurrence.
> - last : Mark duplicates as True except for the last occurrence.
> - False :Mark all duplicates as True.